# Finding letters within items in lists in Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to go through a list to find letter combinations that don't exist in English. After a fair amount of arguing, I have a word list that I can mess with. Each word is listed as 'word\n' since each word is on a line. If I wanted to find, say, the word 'winter', if in works but only if I'm looking for 'winter\n'. I can't look just for 'winter' so I can't find individual letter pairs which is the goal.

There's over a quarter million items, so I can't cycle through the list every time, it would take ages. I don't care about index, I just need a true/false of if a letter pair is anywhere in the list.

Sorry if this was a bit rambly, I hope I got my point across. Thanks!

Comment: Did you try `split` method? Like `str.split('\n')[0]` might give you `winter`

Comment: You can use `line.rstrip()` to remove the newlines.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you don't want to alter your wordlist, it sounds like you're looking for something like this:

```py
def search(word_list, word): # word_list is your list of words, word is the word you're searching for
    for w in word_list: # iterate over the list
        if w.startswith(word): # check if any of them start with the word you're looking for
            return True # return true if a match is found
    return False # return false if no matches are found
```

If you instead want to find a substring anywhere in a word instead of at the beginning, replace `w.startswith(word)` with `word in w`.

Comment: there's nearly 235k words and i have 676 combinations to check, i don't think i can loop thru every time

Comment: actually, upon trying, it only takes a few seconds per run. should take less than an hour at 5 seconds a loop.

Comment: a `set` instead of a `list` would be much faster

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do that but the easiest one is like this:

```
flag = True
STRING = 'YOUR STRING'

def check(letter):
        for k in range(33 ,127):
                if chr(k) == letter:
                        return True

        return False

for i in STRING:
        if not check(i):
                break
                flag = False
```

The reason for 33 and 127 in for loop is that they are the ascii code for English words and other things(such as: ?,!,*,(,), etc)
Notice: This code is just for one string!
And also you can use regex library to do that.
You can create a variable like pattern like this:

```
pattern = '[A-Za-z]'
```

this pattern is for all of the English letters.
And then:

```
new_string = re.sub(pattern,STRING,'')
if new_string == '':
    flag = True
else:
    flag = False
```

sub method is just like replace and you give a pattern, a string and the replace for pattern in string.

So we replace all of the English letters in a string with '' and when there is nothing left on your string it means that your string is made of English letters.
But I'm not sure about syntax for re. You have to take look at doc.
**If you are looking for a fast algorithm, DO NOT USE THE FIRST WAY! BECAUSE THE ORDER OF CODE IS O(2) FOR A SINGLE STRING(NOT A LIST)**